# _mint vs _safeMint, which is best for ERC721?

Tags: solidity, erc-721

Is there a relevant difference for an ER721 contract? Is there a difference in gas cost?

Answer (score 15):

I am familiar to which implementations you are referring. (As this is not a specified ERC-721 feature.)

The `_safeMint` flavor of minting causes the recipient of the tokens, if it is a smart contract, to react upon receipt of the tokens.

Here is a general consideration to help you decide which one to use:

- If YOU are paying for the minting of tokens, use `_mint`. The `_safeMint` might cost you an arbitrary amount of money because of choices made by the recipient of the tokens. This is enough to deter you from considering it.
- If THEY are paying for the minting of tokens and you expect buyers to be composing functionality with smart contracts, use `_safeMint`. There is some marginal benefit of allowing the extra features with smart contracts this allows.
- If THEY are paying and you expect INDIVIDUAL PEOPLE to buy tokens, then use `_mint`. The extra features in `_safeMint` are not expected.

The extra cost from using `_safeMint` is non-zero. And cost is also always a concern.

Comment: Would really help here if you can elaborate who `YOU` and `THEY` are and whether you're talking about paying for the gas fee or paying for mint of the token (payable).

Comment: Above "YOU" is the contract designer/administrator who is deploying the contract. "THEY" are the customers of your product (i.e. "hodlers").

Comment: This is an amazingly helpful answer. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent answer William. I like how you gave different scenarios and framed them in terms of what we are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

`_mint` and `_safeMint` are not part of the [ERC721](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-721/) *standard*, so you should check the specific implementation of those methods to see what are the differences in the smart contract. Even differences in gas costs can only be verified looking at the code (plus sometimes the current state of the chain) and cannot be derived only by the interface.

This is always true for every smart contract, not only for those exposing a *standard* interface.

Please note also that, like other ERC token *standards* (i.e. ERC20), the specification is useful only to share the signature of the methods (name and parameters) to be able to interoperate with other smart contracts and application, but it does not impose a specific implementation nor it allow you to check if the smart contract behaves as you expected under the hood. Again, you must always check the code by your own.