# OpenZeppelin ERC721: difference between safeMint and mint

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin, mint

Can you highlight the core difference between two functions: `mint` and `safeMint`? Why its called "safe"? and when both of them should use? cause, for me, functions' syntax is pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

There was the answer here:
[_mint vs _safeMint, which is best for ERC721?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115280/mint-vs-safemint-which-is-best-for-erc721)

---

To summarize, `safeMint` is there to prevent someone minting ERC721 to a contract which does not support ERC721 transfer. So the ERC721 token is stuck there forever. If you are sure this won't happen, you can directly use `_mint` to save the gas cost.

See more: [ERC721.sol#L262](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L262)